# Distance matrix along a dimension

Tags: python, numpy

Assuming that I want to compute a distance matrix between every element in a vector, I can do that in the following way:

```
X = np.array([1, 2, 3])
dist = np.triu(np.expand_dims(X, 0) - np.expand_dims(X, 1))
# [[0 1 2]
#  [0 0 1]
#  [0 0 0]]
```

However, I am not sure how should I do the same if `X` is a matrix, and I want to compute the pairwise distances for every vector. For example, assuming that I have the following matrix:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 5, 7],[7, 8, 9]])
```

I would expect to get the following output:

```
# [[[0 1 2],
#   [0 0 1],
#   [0 0 0]],
#
#  [[0 4 6],
#   [0 0 2],
#   [0 0 0]],
# 
#  [[0 1 2],
#   [0 0 1],
#   [0 0 0]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.triu` on `3D` extended arrays subtracted version -

```
In [57]: np.triu(X[:,None,:]-X[:,:,None])
Out[57]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

Or to use your *trusty* `np.expand_dims` -

```
np.triu(np.expand_dims(X, 1) - np.expand_dims(X, 2))
```

Or create a `triu` mask with something like `np.tri` and then mask -

```
mask = ~np.tri(X.shape[-1], dtype=bool)
out = mask*(X[:,None,:]-X[:,:,None])
```

Comment: Awesome! The first variant easily translates to `PyTorch` as well so thats the one!